# Open a webpage and click a button in Android

Tags: java, android

What I want to do is within my Android App, when I press a button, I want to open this webpage (in code) and press the "OPEN" button. How would I accomplish this in Java / Android?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Webpage</title>
</head>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['OPEN']))
{
exec("<link here>");
}

?>


<form method="post">
<button name="OPEN"> Open</button><br>

</form>
</html>
```

My code in Android that solves this - thanks for the very big hint @his

```
            String RPI_IP = "http://192.172.26.1/index.php";
    String param = "OPEN=";

      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(RPI_IP);

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("OPEN", ""));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is a simple `form` without any Javascript then you don't need to simulate a browser or the clicking. You simply would use `HTTPClient` to build a `POST` request and set the parameter `OPEN` appropriately.

Comment: It's just the code you see above - HTML + PHP. Is there a code sample for that? Thanks for the very quick answer